# Use variables in paths in crontab

Tags: cron, shell

The crontab I use is more complex but I broke the problem down to a minimal problem set.

My crontab is working like this:

```
mypath='/home/user/opt/script_home'
myscript='/home/user/opt/script_home/myscript.py'
* * * * * "$myscript"
```

But not like this:

```
mypath='/home/user/opt/script_home'
myscript="${mypath}/myscript.py"
* * * * * "$myscript"
```

Error message in maildir:

```
/bin/sh: ${mypath}/myscript.py: No such file or directory
```

The python interpreter is available under the restricted cron $PATH, so that is not the issue.

Edit: Also, if I run the crontab using bash or sh it runs without errors. (After removing * * * * * of course)

It may be that I am missing something very basic here, but I wrapped my head around it for some time now and searched the web. But I had no luck with my search parameters so far. The crontab is working with the ugly usage of the common path at several positions, but that is not good code and therefore bothers me. Please help me out of my agony =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: you can't.

according to `man 5 crontab`

> The value string is not parsed for environmental substitutions or replacement of variables, thus lines like
>
> ```
> PATH = $HOME/bin:$PATH
> ```
>
> will not work as you might expect.

`cron`'s parser is not as powerfull as `bash`'s.

Comment: I might want to add that it shouldn't be, cron is only supposed to run scripts, and those should do the heavy lifting. Cron is supposed to be as lightweight as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure mypath this variable in .bash_profile or .bashrc file then it will be accessible.

```
vi .bash_profile or vi .bashrc
```

then add below path and save

```
 mypath='/home/user/opt/script_home'
```

Answer (score 0):

Since cron is neither and interactive nor login shell, neither .bashrc nor .bash_profile are sourced. So if you define mypath in those files you will not have that variable while using cron.
Up to my knowledge, the only way to have it in cron is to define it directly (i.e. without environmental substitutions or replacement of variables, as said before) in the crontab script.